# how to do dispatch and function on onclick

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to send a data to a reducer and also do a function that should get the data I send to a reducer and send to the server
                    here i wont to send to reducer

```
                   <Fab aria-label="delete"
                      value={vacation.id}
                      key={vacation.id}
                  >>>onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE', payload: vacation.id })}>

                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </Fab>
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    Vacations: [],
};

export function Vacations(state = initialState, action) {
    // console.log('Vacations-action', action.payload);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_VACATIONS':
            return {
                ...state,
                Vacations: action.payload
            };
        case 'DELETE':
            return {
                deleteCard: action.payload            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And my fuction

```
  const DeleteCard = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: 'DELETE', payload: deleteCard })
    alert(deleteCard)
    const confirm = window.confirm(`You are sure you want to delete vacation number ?${deleteCard}`);
    if (confirm == true) {
      axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/users/admin/delete/${deleteCard}`)
    } else {
      alert("You pressed Cancel!")
    }
  };
```

The useSelector i wont to get

```
  //dispatch redux
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    role = 2,
    username,
 >>>>>deleteCard,
  } = useSelector(state => ({
    ...state.combineReducers,
    ...state.userReducer,
    ...state.vacationsReducer
  }));
```

**Basically what I'm looking for is to do 2 things in onClick and the function will basically be action of tunk**

Comment: What I understood is when you are deleting one item at the same time after Deletion api call you want to get the data and update store, right?

Comment: After the api call, I want to delete from the store every time the admin makes a card delete

Comment: I'm not getting what are you trying to do when you calling `DeleteCard`, if the user won't accept deleting so what's happening? It feels like you need to change the logic, for example first asking for deleting the card, then dispatching the delete action

Comment: I just want to delete the ID from api

Comment: So why you need the delete action?

Comment: I just want to delete the card from the list and to delete it I want the id I send to the store from there I want to get the id and put the delete function